# Downcasting a non pointer with reference

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I would like to know the child type of a parent class. The problem is the parent class I'm getting is returned from a function by reference &. I could not resolve it. Here is an example of piece of code of what is going on:

```
class A : public B { ... }

B& getB() { return _b; }

main ()
{
    ...
    B aux = getB(); //this already gives me problems
    // ?? now what I have to do to know if B is a an A?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: if you want help solving a problem, you should probably explain what the problem is. Not just "gives me problems".

Comment: Your question makes no sense. B is always an A. The hierarchy is this way. B is a A.

Comment: @mkaes It looks like `A` is a `B`, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as you define `aux` to be a `B`, it really will be a `B`, even if `getB` actually returned a reference to an `A`.  This is called slicing, and is almost certainly not what you want; there's no way to undo it.

The reason it happened is that you copied the return value of `getB`.  If, instead, you bound a reference like this

```
B& aux = getB();
```

then `aux` would simply refer to whatever `getB` had returned.  If you're sure that the reference `getB` returned was bound to an `A` you can use `static_cast<A&>(aux)` to access the `A` parts of it.  If you're not sure, but if you know `B` has at least one virtual function, you can use `dynamic_cast<A&>(aux)`; it'll throw an exception if it fails.

That said, if you have a reference or pointer to a base type, trying to find out what derived type it secretly refers to is often a sign of bad design.  What happens if the value is of a type you didn't know about yet?  There's a good chance you wanted to put this logic into a virtual member function, or perhaps wanted a more [union-like structure](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/variant.html).